# Typescript Clean Architecture and In-Memory Database/ Repository

Tags: typescript, clean-architecture

I am implementing clean architecture in my current project and I am struggling with repositories and data sources and terminology.

I would like to test my `useCases` with in-memory repository because I only care about my business logic at this stage. But I cannot make sense of the terminology and would like to ask about it.

I defined a base `DataSource` like this:

```
export interface DataSource<T> {    
    create(request: any): Promise<T>

    // more methods here but removed for simplicity
}
```

Then I defined my interface for `Patient` like this:

```
export interface PatientRepository {
    createPatient(patient: Patient): Promise<void>

    // more methods here but removed for simplicity
}
```

I will be using a `Sequelize` for production and for unit testing just a local array of `entities`.

If I am doing an implementation of the `PatientRepository` do I:

**Option 1**

I create a `PatientSequelizeRepository` which will implement the methods in my contract and it will extend an abstract `SequelizeRepository` that implements the `DataSource` contract. Then I would also create a `PatientInMemoryRepository` which will implement the same methods and it will extend and abstract `InMemoryRepository` that implements the `DataSource` contract. Then in my `use-case` I import the `PatientInMemoryRepository` and in my composition of the `app` I would import the `PatientSequelizeRepository`?

**Option 2**

I create one implementation of the `PatientRepository` and assign a `data-source` into constructor because the methods for the `PatientRepository` are the same. I would also have a generic `InMemoryDataSource` and `SequelizeDataSource` that would both implement the `DataSource` contract. So by default I am constructing the repository with `Sequelize` implementation but I am also giving the opportunity to use other data sources if needed

```
export class PatientRepositoryImpl implements PatientRepository {
    constructor(dataSource: DataSource<Patient>) { }
    
    async createPatient(patient: Patient) {
       return this.dataSource.create(patient)
    }
}

export const patientRepository = new PatientRepositoryImpl(new SequelizeDataSource())
```

Here I get confused of the naming. I am inserting a `SequelizeDataSource` into the constructor, but should I create a `PatientSequelizeDataSource`, insert this into the constructor and do the same with `PatientInMemoryDataSource`? What would be the best action here? Is there maybe an option 3 I haven't thought about?

Comment: Option 2 sounds best to me: you take advantage of the interface and end up with a simpler design by favoring composition over inheritance, but if I am following you, your app doesn't care anyway because you import a patient repository which encapsulates the persistence mechanism.

You lost me with `PatientSequelizeDataSource` though. What would it do that `SequelizeDataSource` would not?

Comment: this question would fit better in softwareengineering.stackexchange.com by the way

Comment: @geoffrey What I meant was that I would create a PatientSequelizeDataSource that would extend a SequelizeDataSource. And then I could just inject that instead of the generic sequelize data source?

Comment: It's what I had understood, but from what information would this protect `ParitentRepository`? It already needs to know how to deal with patient-related stuff because that's its purpose. In my opinion there is no need for this. If your data-source object encapsulates technical details for fetching data that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The key question regarding repositories in Clean Architecture is: Is the [Dependency Rule](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) violated?

Assuming your Repository is implemented in the "interface adapters" layer and your DataSource is implemented in the "frameworks layer then your Repository must not have any dependency to a concreate DataSource implementation.

From that perspective the Option 2 would match the Dependency Rule if "by default I am constructing the repository with Sequelize implementation" means that in the "main" component of your application you are injecting the Sequelize implementation into the Repository constructor and NOT create the Sequelize instance in the default constructor of the Repository.

A more detailed discussion on how to implement repositories in Clean Architecture correctly you can find [in this video](https://youtu.be/pfhDO_hZixw)